# Caracteres extraños al analizar un html con lxml y requests en python

Tags: html, python, python-requests

Mi problema es que cuando extraigo un texto de un sitio web que genera palbaras aleatoriamente cuando esta tiene tildes me lo muestra con caracteres raros y no se como solucionarlo.
Estoy utilizando lxml y requests para analizar la información.

**Ejemplo:** La palabra es 'piña' y me genera 'piã±a'.

```
import requests 
from lxml import etree

Response=requests.get('https://www.palabrasaleatorias.com/')


html=etree.fromstring(html.text,etree.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8',recover=True))

word=word.xpath('body/center/center/table/tr/td/div')[0].text

print(word)
```

Comment: Probé esta respuesta del sitio en inglés y me funcionó perfecto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52615216/12913664

Comment: @dante-s Me funcionó, gracias

Comment: De nada Jose c: